# Image rotation in Magento

Tags: magento, rotation, php

I am trying to add a rotation function for images that vendors upload to my shop. I have added a rotation button which you will see in my phtml code below. The rotation button is on the thumbnail of the uploaded image. I am having difficulty with my php code. I want it to get the image data, rotate it and save it. Thanks.

My phtml:

```
<article class="item">
        {{if url}}
        <a href="{{:url}}" class="preview lightbox">
        {{else}}
        <a class="preview">
        {{/if}}
            <button class="sort" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Drag to sort') ?>"></button>
            <span class="error-message" data-tooltip='<?php echo json_encode($tooltipError) ?>'><?php echo $helper->__('Error') ?></span>
            <span class="starred" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Default image') ?>" data-tooltip='<?php echo json_encode($tooltipDefault) ?>'></span>
            <button class="remove" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Delete image') ?>"></button>
            <button class="rotate" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Rotate image') ?>"></button>
            <img class="thumbnail" onload="var img = jQuery(this); setTimeout(function () {img.next('.loader').remove();}, 1200);" {{if thumbnailUrl}}src="{{:thumbnailUrl}}"{{else}}href="{{:url}}"{{/if}}/>
            <span class="loader"></span>
        </a>
    </article>
```

My php:

```
public function productRotateImageAction()
{
    $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api")->getMediaUrl($image['file']);
    $gallery->getBackend()->rotateImage($image->getFile());
    $degrees = 90;
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
    imagejpeg($rotate);
    imagedestroy($source);
    imagedestroy($rotate);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:
http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Image/Varien_Image.html Try using Varien classes to maipulate images.

Comment: So like this?

`code
public function productRotateImageAction()
    {
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Media_Api $mediaApi */
        $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("product_attribute_media_api");
        $image = new Varien_Image($mediaApi);
        $image->rotate(90);
    }`

Comment: $image = new Varien_Image($filePath); $image->rotate(90);

Comment: $image->save($newPath);